# How Can I Remove The Red Squiggly Lines From My Code? (It's Working Perfectly) - IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter, underline

Screenshot of my issue(Red Squiggly lines in my dart code)

[image: Screenshot of my issue(Red Squiggly lines in my dart code)]

Comment: Have you tried "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Comment: I have. It's still there

Comment: What are the error messages? You may open Dart Analysis tool window to see them all.

Comment: There aren't any error messages

Comment: Could you accidentally mess up your code highlighting settings? Try to open Settings | Editor | Color Scheme and switch scheme to Darcula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution to this.

It seems that some of the plug-ins already installed are conflicting with dart and thereby, showing the code as red even when no error is there or even if all SDK are properly set-up.

For me, turning off **'Deadalus support'**  plugin and restarting and invalidating cache worked. For some others, it was the **github** plugin. So, give it a shot and see which one is causing the red code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just import material widgets like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

Comment: I have imported everything. The code is working perfectly. The squiggly lines are just distracting.